# The current URL did not match any of these, include() giving problems

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I decided to make a `urls.py` for each app. However I am running into problems when I `include` the urls. I do not know what is the problem as I have done everything right. My site has the same structure as the Django 1.9 tutorial. I have `template` folder at the root, and also a `template` directory inside `myapp` like so `template\myapp\`. `home.html` and `profile.html` are in `myapp\template\myapp\`

Only the urls in `myapp` are giving problems that consequently renders neither `home.html` nor `profile.html` which gives the

> Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL
>   patterns, in this order:
>
> ```
> ^$ [name='index']
> ^myapp/
> ^admin/
> ```
>
> The current URL, profile, didn't match any of these.

Error. I could get them working by writing all `urls` directly in the main site `mysite`, by importing their `views` but I rather have things more organized and let each app have their own `urls.py`. I have also registered `myapp` and placed `myapp` under `INSTALLED_APPS`

myapp: view

```
from django.shortcuts import render


    def home(request):
        return render(request, 'myapp/home.html')


    def profile(request):
        return render(request, 'myapp/profile.html')
```

myapp urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .import views

app_name = 'myapp'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^home/$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^profile/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
]
```

mysite urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from .import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),    

    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: "The current URL didn't match any of these". the error is highlighted in the post.

Comment: I meant for full error traceback.

Comment: In my console the only thing I see is `Not Found: /home/
[10/Aug/2016 08:52:14] "GET /home/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2144`. Normally you see a bunch of lines in the console along with the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be going to just /profile, but you don't have that defined as a URL, you have /myapp/profile.

Comment: No not just "/profile", it is also done for ''/home" as well, if I try to go to `home` or `profile` the error pops up. According to the documentation for in app templates you write `app_name/template_name`, if you do not do this Django will not find the url. Assuming your template structure for apps is like this `app_name/templates/app_name/`

Comment: Sigh. You don't have URLs for *either* /home or /profile. You have /myapp/home and /myapp/profile. I'm not sure why you're mentioning templates here, they have nothing at all to do with this; this is about URLs.

Comment: The urls are in the urls.py file, for `home` I have `url(r'^home/$', views.home, name='home')`. Or maybe what I have done is not right at all. From my understanding the the `include` in `mysite\urls.py` should be including the urls I have in `myapp\urls.py`
`

Comment: Yes I know that. But you *include* that urls.py under the prefix "myapp/".

Comment: What is the correct way of including them? that is what I see in the docs `include('app_name.urls')`

Comment: I really don't know what to tell you. The include part is fine; the issue is with the path. What you have done is correct if you want your URLs to be /myapp/home etc. If you don't want that, then use a different path to include them under.

Comment: I think I figured out the problem with your help thanks.